# PHP/Laravel 5.4 "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email, laravel-5

I have a basic array of emails that I am attempting to foreach over in order to assign the values to another variable to send via Laravel mail. Here is a dump and die of the array, `$emails`, prior to the foreach:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "test@example.com"
  1 => "testTwo@example.com"
  2 => "testThree@example.com"
  3 => "testFour@example.com"
]
```

And the foreach is:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $this->bcc = $email;
}
```

I'm not sure why I'd be getting this error, as this is clearly an array. Ultimately I am attempting to send to multiple emails, but just assigning this array to the mailable's bcc:

```
$this->bcc = $emails;
```

results in the error `Illegal string offset 'address'`, though a dump and die of `$this` shows the array is in the `bcc` property:

[image]

Anyone see the core issue here, beyond my lack of knowledge regarding sending multiple emails with Laravel? Cheers!

Comment: I feel like you need to share more code, `address` isn't in your code but is clearly causing a problem. Can you share more code?

Comment: You're putting an array, in an object, so when you parse the object, it finds the array, but it will not parse this, So you would need to put another `foreach($email as $em){ //statement }` in the `foreach' you currently have. But to avoid problems, since there can also be some other types besides an array in the object, do a check if it's an array or not.

Comment: @AndyHolmes, That's coming from Laravel's Mailable.php. I'm not really sure how to resolve that yet, but it's on my radar. There's a buildRecipients method: foreach (['to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo'] as $type) {
            foreach ($this->{$type} as $recipient) {
                $message->{$type}($recipient['address'], $recipient['name']);
            }
        }

Comment: @Rick_Jellema, Thanks, I added a check: if (is_array($emails) || is_object($emails)) {
            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                $this->bcc = $email;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because the bcc() function is expecting an array or an array of arrays with the "address" key.

Try something like this:

```
$emailArray = [];

foreach($emails as $email) {
  emailArray[]["address"] = $email;
  emailArray[]["name"] = "testname";
}

$this->bcc = $emailArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, but they're coming from a comma separated list from a DOM input.

Comment: Then you need to parse it so that it has the above form. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by sending a string of addresses, rather than an array and then just exploding the string into a keyed array:

```
class ContactEmail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

private $data;
public $body;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data['data'];
    $this->body = $this->data['body'];
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $addresses = explode(', ', $this->data['emails']);

    return $this->bcc($addresses)
                ->subject($this->data['subject'])
                ->markdown('emails.CustomerContact.Custom');
}
```

}